# JOLT transform: sub-object to top object

Tags: java, apache-nifi, jolt

I use Apache NIFI. I need transform JSON in JSON with JoltTransformJSON processor.
I have JSON:

```
[ {
  "code" : "01.11.11.111-00001",
  "version" : "1",
  "inclusionDate" : "2018-06-16T05:53:14+04:00",
  "publishDate" : "2018-06-16T05:53:14+04:00",
  "name" : "????",
  "actual" : "false",
  "applicationDateStart" : "2018-06-16T00:00:00+04:00",
  "applicationDateEnd" : "2018-06-16T00:00:00+04:00",
  "cancelInfo" : {
    "cancelDate" : "2018-06-17T00:00:00+04:00",
    "cancelReason" : "????????? ???? ????????? ?????????? ??????? ????."
  },
  "nsiDescription" : "",
  "isTemplate" : "false",
  "noNewFeatures" : "false"
}, {
  "code" : "01.11.11.111-00002",
  "version" : "1",
  "inclusionDate" : "2018-06-21T04:21:14+04:00",
  "publishDate" : "2018-06-21T04:21:14+04:00",
  "name" : "????",
  "actual" : "false",
  "applicationDateStart" : "2018-06-21T00:00:00+04:00",
  "applicationDateEnd" : "2018-06-22T00:00:00+04:00",
  "cancelInfo" : {
    "cancelDate" : "2018-06-22T00:00:00+04:00",
    "cancelReason" : "????????? ???? ????????? ?????????? ??????? ????."
  },
  "isTemplate" : "false",
  "noNewFeatures" : "false"
} ]
```

How I can transform this part of JSON

```
  "cancelInfo" : {
    "cancelDate" : "2018-06-22T00:00:00+04:00",
    "cancelReason" : "????????? ???? ????????? ?????????? ??????? ????."
  },
```

In this JSON. Transform with JOLT.

```
[ {
  "code" : "01.11.11.111-00001",
  "version" : "1",
  "inclusionDate" : "2018-06-16T05:53:14+04:00",
  "publishDate" : "2018-06-16T05:53:14+04:00",
  "name" : "????",
  "actual" : "false",
  "applicationDateStart" : "2018-06-16T00:00:00+04:00",
  "applicationDateEnd" : "2018-06-16T00:00:00+04:00",
  "cancelDate" : "2018-06-17T00:00:00+04:00",
  "cancelReason" : "????????? ???? ????????? ?????????? ??????? ????.",
  "nsiDescription" : "",
  "isTemplate" : "false",
  "noNewFeatures" : "false"
}, {
  "code" : "01.11.11.111-00002",
  "version" : "1",
  "inclusionDate" : "2018-06-21T04:21:14+04:00",
  "publishDate" : "2018-06-21T04:21:14+04:00",
  "name" : "????",
  "actual" : "false",
  "applicationDateStart" : "2018-06-21T00:00:00+04:00",
  "applicationDateEnd" : "2018-06-22T00:00:00+04:00",
  "cancelDate" : "cancelDate" : "2018-06-22T00:00:00+04:00",
  "cancelReason" : "????????? ???? ????????? ?????????? ??????? ????.",
  "isTemplate" : "false",
  "noNewFeatures" : "false"
} ]
```

I can't make a JOLT specification. Tell me also where you can see its full description, I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

I use this cheme for slove my problem:

```
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
        "*": {
              "@": "",
              "cancelInfo": {
                "cancelDate": "cancelInfo_cancelDate",
                "cancelReason": "cancelInfo_cancelReason"
              }
      }
    }
  }
```